Replace text in textbox Apache Poi 5.3.0
If you follow the example from this post, then how to find the created textbox? I have this:
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("The Body text: ");

        CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();

        CTRect ctRect = ctGroup.addNewRect();
        ctRect.addNewWrap().setType(STWrapType.SQUARE);
        ctRect.setStyle("position:absolute;mso-position-horizontal:center;margin-top:40pt;width:100pt;height:24pt");
        ctRect.setFillcolor("#FFFF00");
        CTTxbxContent ctTxbxContent = ctRect.addNewTextbox().addNewTxbxContent();
        ctTxbxContent.addNewP().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The TextBox text...");

        Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode();
        CTPicture ctPicture = null;
        try {
            ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
        } catch (XmlException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        run=paragraph.createRun();
        CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
        cTR.addNewPict();
        cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);

but when I go through these objects, I don't find the text in block I created using the code.
document.getParagraphs().getRuns().foreach(run->{
 run.getPictList().foreach(pict->System.out.println(pict.getDomNode().getTextContent()));
});


Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Extract and print the picture text from the Word document using Apache POI, you can use this code :
document.getParagraphs().forEach(xwpfParagraph -> {
        xwpfParagraph.getRuns().forEach(xwpfRun -> {
            if(!StringUtils.isBlank(xwpfRun.getPictureText())){
                xwpfRun.getPictureText();
                System.out.println( xwpfRun.getPictureText());
            }
        });
    });

Add the following dependencies to your pom.xml :
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>




Unfortunately it didn't work.  The console is empty.

Please check whether the text is present inside the pictureText function or not. I have now shared the results and debugged the scenario based on my previous answer.
